# The minimum value from each category

Tags: mysql

I want to get out the minimum price for categories 1, 2 and 3
I've used

```
   LEAST(MIN(price_reduced),MIN(price))
   IFNULL(MIN(price_reduced),MIN(price)) ... WHERE price <> 0 and price_reduced <> 0
```

Database

| id | category | price | price_reduced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 300 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 500 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 200 | 150 |
| 5 | 2 | 125 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | 300 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | 200 | 90 |

Output

```
1 - 100
2 - 125
3 - 90
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will work on all MySQL V4+ :

```
SELECT Category, 
MIN(IF((price_reduced > 0) AND (price_reduced < price), price_reduced, price)) AS P 
FROM your_table GROUP BY Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `cte`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT category,
       MIN(price) AS mp,
       MIN(CASE WHEN price_reduced <= 0 THEN 9999 ELSE price_reduced END) pr
  FROM mytable 
GROUP BY category)
SELECT category, LEAST(mp, pr) AS min_val
  FROM cte;
```

Or without `cte` but with derived table:

```
SELECT category, LEAST(mp, pr) AS min_val
  FROM (SELECT category,
       MIN(price) AS mp,
       MIN(CASE WHEN price_reduced <= 0 THEN 9999 ELSE price_reduced END) pr
  FROM mytable 
GROUP BY category) a;
```

Or just a single query:

```
SELECT category,
       LEAST(MIN(price),
       MIN(CASE WHEN price_reduced <= 0 THEN 9999 ELSE price_reduced END)) AS min_val
  FROM mytable 
GROUP BY category;
```

All return the same results.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TAwx5j9G)